# Fail to upload application to App Store (iTunes Store Operation Failed)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I had start to upload application since 9 Nov 2017 until 10 Nov 2017 with Xcode 9.1.
I'm still facing issue to upload the application as below:

"iTunes Store Operation Failed.
The network connection was lost"

[image]

Besides, I had try to export and upload from Appliction loader.
I get the error: ''You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request."

[image]

Get another error from application loader. It's apple connection got problem?

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Have you validated the build/archive you are trying to submit? Have you checked if the CFBundleIdentifier is missing or is not matching with the app on iTunes connect?

Comment: I check it, CFBundleIdentifier is same as iTunes Connect there and validate with build/archive which get the same error as above "iTunes Store Operation Failed. The network connection was lost"

Comment: do a clean build in xcode. Use a different network (wifi/3g) and try to upload it using application-loader

Comment: use application loader, after restarting the Xcode.

Comment: What's the size of the ipa? Are you sure your connectivity is fine? Try creating a sample app on iTunesconnect and build an empty app and upload. does that also fail?